# Do this odds of $12/25$'s question have a solution(s) with no coincidences?

Tags: probability

Given just the first $25$ positive integers, $2$ of them randomly chosen. The odds of an even sum are $12$ per $25$. The odds of an even number randomly chosen are $12$ per $25$, my girlfriend said. My solution has no good ideas, I wondered about another one(s) better, here is mine (coincidentally?!):

> $$\frac{\textrm{C}_{13}^{2}+ \textrm{C}_{12}^{2}}{\textrm{C}_{25}^{2}}= \frac{12}{25}$$

I'm so amazed why we have to find the probability by choosing an even number firstly, surely, I can't imagine that the above e. g's game is totally random, I need to the help to understand how was

Comment: Newly here, but why was my question down-voted? I'm so confused!

Comment: I'm adding some New Thangs then!

Comment: Hi. You will have better luck by improving the title (making it relevant for your quesiton), and adding the "self-study" tag.

Comment: Every time you edit the question it shifts the page. You've now edited the question something like $10$ times in one minute. Please consider which edits you would like to carry out and then perform them all in one.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I can't understand how that was, I'll never edit one more time!

Comment: There are too much understood here: https://diendantoanhoc.net/topic/191360-ch%E1%BB%A9ng-minh-r%E1%BA%B1ng-x%C3%A1c-su%E1%BA%A5t-%C4%91%E1%BB%83-ch%E1%BB%8Dn-%C4%91%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3c-2-s%E1%BB%91-t%E1%BB%B1-nhi%C3%AAn-kh%C3%A1c-nhau-trong-t%E1%BA%ADp-h%E1%BB%A3p-s%E1%BB%91-%C4%91%C3%B3-m%C3%A0-t%E1%BB%95ng-c/#entry732647

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evenness plays two different roles here. The problem is perhaps a bit easier to think about if we separate those two roles. So consider $12$ amber marbles and $13$ scarlet marbles in a bag. You draw two marbles – what’s the probability that they have the same colour? (This corresponds to your numbers having the same parity and thus summing to an even number.)

There are $4$ types of pairs: $(a,a)$, $(a,s)$, $(s,a)$ and $(s,s)$, with probabilities $p_{aa}$, $p_{as}$, $p_{sa}$ and $p_{ss}$, respectively. The probability to draw two marbles of the same colour is $p_{aa}+p_{ss}$. Now note that the probability to draw an amber marble when you draw a single marble is $p_{aa}+p_{as}$, since you can just ignore the second of the two marbles drawn.

So the question becomes whether it’s a coincidence that in your case $p_{aa}+p_{ss}=p_{aa}+p_{as}$, that is, that $p_{ss}=p_{as}$. It isn’t: Since there is one more scarlet marble, each scarlet marble can form the same number of pairs with scarlet and amber marbles (since it can’t form a pair with itself).

Comment: Copy that! Thank you, @joriki

Comment: That's what I want!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of $25$, let the upper limit be $n$ with $n$ odd.  Let $k=\frac 12(n-1)$, like your $12$. Your answer becomes
$$\frac {(C_{k+1}^2)^2+(C_{k}^2)^2}{(C_{m}^2)^2}=\frac{(k+1)\cdot k +k\cdot (k-1)}{n\cdot 2k}=\frac {2k}{2n}=\frac kn$$
so it is not an accident.

Comment: That's as same as mine, I want a fresh solution, however, thank you very much!

Comment: @bamboo_jivy271:  did you hit the downvote along with accept?  It seems strange to get both at the same time.

Comment: No, it's not mine!

Comment: Because I'm $-4$ then!

Comment: @bamboo_jjvy271:  you expressed surprise that the answer comes out $\frac kn$.  I showed it was not an accident of $25$.  If you have a solution, you should show it.  What are you hoping for as "another solution"?

Comment: No, what I meant is what my girlfriend said. I just post my proof for it!

Comment: @RossMillikan: I'd say it's even less of a coincidence than your arithmetic would suggest (see my answer) :-)